# How can I use typed IDs for JPA entities in Spring Boot with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate to develop applications, and I would like to enhance the type safety of my JPA entities' IDs. Currently, the ID field is defined as a `Long`, but I want to provide it with an explicit type. Here's an example of what I have:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
}
```

I want to modify this code to give the ID field a more specific type. Here's what I have in mind:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Id id;

  record Id(Long id) {}
}
```

By introducing a nested record class called `Id`, I can ensure that only instances of this class are used as IDs for the `User` entity. This approach allows me to avoid accidentally passing another entity's ID as a parameter since it's no longer just a `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

1. Make your Id a separate, public class that extends Number.
2. Create a converter class (annotated with @Converter(autoApply = true)) that implements AttributeConverter<Id, Long>
3. Rename your Id class to something like UserId, because the name will conflict with the @Id annotation.
4. Change your id field's GenerationType from IDENTITY to AUTO to allow your persistence provider to adopt a more flexible strategy for the strongly typed id.
5. Add the @Convert(converter = <insert your converter class's name here>.class) annotation to your id field in the entity.

You should now be operational.

Edit: several edits were made to amend the steps to eliminate problems I encountered working through this.